# how to view master page in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

just learning master page, i have a master page which include a content. but how to view the page .master in browser? what it the url?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't; You must also create `.aspx` page using that master page then you can see the .aspx page.

Comment: The idea of a master page is to provide a template for your child pages. Any child page that inherits this master page will have this master markup in it. You cannot directly view a master page in a browser, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: i don't understand , but the master page include header.aspx, body.aspx, left.aspx, which page should i view?

Comment: I think you should explore more about how http protocol works and what is the difference between static and dynamic web page. Web Browsers only know `html` markup, browser dont understand asp.net, php, jsp and all. When you request a .aspx page - ASP.NET engine generates html markup by combining .master page + .aspx content page and resulting `html` is sent to web browser as response. Please refer image in below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, you can not view master page (.master) in browser** - because it is `not an actual page` but a Control which encloses the content of .aspx pages.

When users request the content pages(.aspx), they merge with the master page (.master) to produce output that combines the layout of the master page with the content from the content page.

A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application.

[image]

For more information please read - [ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: if the master page include header.aspx, body.aspx, left.aspx, which page should i view?

Comment: master page will act as only template and you will specify in header.aspx, body.aspx, left.aspx pages that which master page you want to use. So, you can only view .aspx pages in web browser but markup of master pages will be part of your content pages (.aspx)

Comment: is it possible to group header.aspx, body.aspx, left.aspx into one name.aspx? i don't want user can access header.aspx, body.aspx, left.aspx directly typing the url

Comment: your header (plz note not .aspx) and left navigation will be part of master page but body will go in your multiple content pages(home.aspx, article.aspx, about.aspx). Master page will have content place holder which will be referred by your content page. Users can not access .master pages from anywhere. In short, master page will include content which is common to multiple pages like nav bar, header, etc.

Comment: please google or bing for `asp.net master pages tutorial` or video tutorials to get a clear vision.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it alone in aspx page and view the aspx page directly

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly view a master page. It's more like a shell\template of what the page is supposed to look like.

However, you can create a new page using the master page you have here, and call that page's Url.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view a master page in the browser. It is not a renderable page.

The master page is referenced by regular .aspx pages with the Master attribute of the @Page directive. The rendering process merges the contents of the page and the master and the results are returned to the client, but the URL is that of the page.

If you wish to see the master page as it is rendered, create an empty page that uses that master, then view the page in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Run This Default2.aspx page to show this page content into master  page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    This Is Your Master Page Content....
</asp:Content>
```