# Trying to call code behind method from boot strap modal using Jquery but every time the error callback method is getting invoked

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call the code behind method `RegisterUser()` on the click event of an html button control, which is present inside a bootstrap modal. And for that I used jquery (the code snippet is given below). But I am not able to call the method every time the error callback method is getting invoked.

**This is the Bootstrap Modal Code**

```html
 <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4>Login</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" runat="server">
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding-top: 0;">

                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Sign in</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp" target="_top" style="color: #333">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                </div>
                <!--
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div style="padding:10px"></div>
            </div>
-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**this is the ajax code that I am using to call the back end method**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Master Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                var mail = $('#email').val();
                var pass = $('#password').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Site.Master/RegisterUser',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/jason',
                    data: '{email:' + mail + 'password:' + pass+ '}',
                    dataType: 'jason',
                    success: function (data) {
                        aler(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }

                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**This is the back end method**

```html
 public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string RegisterUser(string email, string password)
        {
            string result = "Congratulations!!! your account has been created.";
            if (email.Length == 0)//Zero length check
            {
                result = "Email Address cannot be blank";
            }
           
            else if (password.Length == 0)
            {
                result = "Password cannot be blank";
            }
            

            return result; ;


        }


    }
```

Comment: What are the error details passed to the callback?

Comment: the data type should be `json` not jason. And `data` is malformed because of improper quoting and spacing. Try creating a javascript object instead of a string for the value of `data` and see if there is any difference.

Comment: `Site.Master` is not a location so you will need to correct `url` also.

Comment: the error details for the callback is "[object Object]"

Comment: There is more to the error function, you won't get anything useful by just `alert`ing it. [See the documentation for the error function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) , it has 3 arguments that you can inspect.

Comment: site.master is the master page name as I am trying to call it from master page itself

Comment: Master pages merge with other content, [you cannot browse to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046052/how-to-view-master-page-in-browser)

Comment: Is this a typo `dataType: 'jason'`? Shouldn't this be `json`? Same goes with `contentType: 'application/jason',`. Your url is incorrect as well. It should be ` url: 'Site1/RegisterUser',`

Comment: @Crowcoder I have used the  error  callback method with other useful parameter and I get the below error details. Please take a look :

event:[object Object]  
jqxhr:error  
Settings:Not Found  
error:undefined